# Refreshing Native ads

Tags: admob, native-ads

> **Refreshing ads**
>
> We recommend that you have ads persist for 60 seconds or longer, depending on the functionality of your app. Our internal tests have
>   shown that this ensures users have enough time to engage with ads,
>   providing the best performance for both advertisers and publishers.
>   Furthermore, these tests have shown that refreshing ads more often can
>   hurt fill rate for our publishers.
>
> If your app is automatically refreshing ads, make sure ad requests are not made when the screen is off. Also, if users navigate to and
>   from pages with ads in an app over a short period of time, a new ad
>   request should not be made sooner than the recommended 60 second rate.

In the Admob Policy it says that **if users navigate to and from pages with ads in an app over a short period of time, a new ad request should not be made sooner than the recommended 60 second rate**.

How can i achieve this in code that when i change to a new activity, a new **Ad Request** is called after the recommended 60s?

Answer (score 1):

Some way to get it done.

1. Using 2 views: First once for content, second for ads to show. Then turn on auto-refresh in Admob setting
2. Using a global variable to check the period of time. Then you can decide to make a new Ad request or not

Comment: So i should make the Adrequest a global variable so i can either show the old request if periode is still less than 60s and after request a new one?

Comment: I think you should not. It may make some wrong on counting and statistic.

Comment: What i'm doing now is using an handler which increments an integer each second and then after the 60s passed i request a new ad. Do you think that will be enough for not violating admob policies?